# GET webdata from a different network

Tags: php, mysql, proxy, html, mod-proxy

Assume that there have 3 servers (**A**, **B** and **C**):

- Server **A** can access server **B** only, and **A** is not able to access **C** directly.
- **B** can access **C**.
- **A**, **C** are in a separate network.

Both **B** and **C** are http servers, but only **C** can run PHP.

I have to use PHP to get some information from MySQL server in **C** from **A**, is it possible to do so?

I cannot install PHP to **B**.

Is it possible to write a PHP page that will run in **C** and return the result to **B** and back to **A**?

Comment: I am nt able to do config on B. The only thing I can do on the B is put web page. And A or C i can config as i like. Mostly like I am not suppose to don config on A seem it may be any client device.

Comment: is it possible for me to use jsp to do the want i want? url = new URL(contentURL);

URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

// show the client the content type:

String contentType = urlConn.getContentType();

response.setContentType(contentType);

// get the input stream
InputStream in = urlConn.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
String contentString = "";

String tmp = br.readLine();
do
{
   contentString += tmp + "\n";
   tmp = br.readLine();
}
while (tmp != null);
   out.flush();
   out.close();
}

Answer (score 1):

Configure B to act as a proxy. If it runs Apache then see the [proxypass directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get B to act as a proxy. The idea being that you just route requests received to B directly to C.

Overview... and you want to get information, which resides on C to A.

## BEFORE

```
(HTTP,PHP) A -----> B (HTTP,PHP)
(HTTP,PHP) A --||   C (HTTP,MySQL)
(HTTP,PHP) B -----> C (HTTP, MySQL)
```

## After

```
(HTTP,PHP)            A -----> B (HTTP->ProxyPass,PHP)
(HTTP,PHP)            A --||   C (HTTP,MySQL)
(HTTP->ProxyPass,PHP) B -----> C (HTTP, MySQL)
```

`A->B(Proxied to)->C`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

### Docs

Suppose the local server has address http://example.com/; then

```
ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://backend.example.com/
```

will cause a local request for http://example.com/mirror/foo/bar to be internally converted into a proxy request to http://backend.example.com/bar.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the idea. But unfortune that I am not able to do any configuration on B. I can only put web on it. I can config on A or C as i like. Is it possible to use webpage to do the thing i want??

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you meant by 'from mysql server in C from A'. I am assuming you mean transferring MySQL data from A to C since A is not an HTTP server(you mentioned only B and C are). You can route a random port let's say 3310 on B to port 3306 on A, this way you will be able to access A's MySQL server directly from C(you would have to enable remote access on A though). I am assuming you have administrator rights on the 3 servers.